# Optimize this SQL Query

Tags: php, sql, mysql, optimization

This SQL query disgusts me. I didn't write it, but it's a massive cause of issues on our servers.  I'm willing to split it up into multiple queries and do some of the processing via PHP (like, the RAND()).

```
$sql = "SELECT a.code, a.ad_id, a.position, a.type, a.image, a.url, a.height, a.width
    FROM " . AD_TABLE ." a, " . USER_GROUP_TABLE . " g
    WHERE (a.max_views >= a.views OR a.max_views = '0')
    AND (FIND_IN_SET(" .$forum_id. ", a.show_forums) > 0 OR a.show_all_forums = '1')
    AND g.user_id = " . $user->data['user_id'] . "
    AND FIND_IN_SET(g.group_id, a.groups)
    AND FIND_IN_SET(" . $user->data['user_rank'] . ", a.ranks)
    AND a.start_time < " . time() . "
    AND a.end_time > " . time() . "
    AND (a.clicks <= a.max_clicks OR a.max_clicks = '0')
    ORDER BY rand()";
```

Yeesh, I feel icky after pasting that...

**EDIT:** Below is the results of the "EXPLAIN" on a sample query in the above format, comma delimited:

```
"id","select_type","table","type","possible_keys","key","key_len","ref","rows","Extra"
1,"SIMPLE","g","ref","user_id","user_id","3","const",6,"Using temporary; Using filesort"
1,"SIMPLE","a","ALL","max_views","","","",10,"Using where"
```

It is

Comment: Are you asking a question, or trying to get some SQL optimised without paying for it?

Comment: Would you mind doing an EXPLAIN SELECT and post the results?

Comment: Disgust is the engine of fix.

Comment: Change your join condition from a find-in-set to a 'like' syntax and try it.

instead of :find-in-set(g.group_id, a.groups)
try : a.groups like '%'. g.group_id . '%'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have three major issues here:

1. `FIND_IN_SET`.

   It's not sargable, an index cannot make it faster. Create a many-to-many relationship table (or tables).

   - `a.start_time < GETDATE() AND a.end_time > GETDATE()`

   `MySQL` is not good in optimizing that. You can keep you timespans as geometry boxes and create a `SPATIAL INDEX` over them, this will be much faster (though less readable)

   - `ORDER BY RAND()`

   If you are using this to sample data (i. e. you don't need all rows but rather a small random subset), there is a more efficient way to do this, described in this article in my blog:

   - [**Selecting random rows**](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/01/selecting-random-rows/)

Answer (score 4):

- You **do not have an explicit join** in this query between table a and table g : they are only related by  find_in_set (g.group_id, a.groups)
- How large is your set in "a.groups" , i.e. does the csv string contain one group-id most of the times?
- If 99% of the cases contain only 1 group, then make a foreach loop over "a.groups" in php and execute a real join (or probably it might eliminate your user_group_table altogether) from the query.

  - For the minority of cases where you have more than 1 group membership, the query will still perform OK with an explicit join.

This will add some more code in your php class/function.

Comment: Ok, how about one more try. This could be very simple . 

Use "and a.groups like " . "%" . g.group_id  . "%"

This will evaluate to "and 'grp1,grp2,grp4' like '%grp1%' " and you will get the hit.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing your problem lies with the dates.

```
AND a.start_time < " . time() . "
AND a.end_time > " . time() . "
```

I would try putting indexes on these fields and see if that helps.  Comparing dates causes the database to compare to each row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute this a lot.. try and use bind variables (instead of string concatenation) .. so the query does not have to be parsed every single time..

edit: Sorry..didn't see the MYSQL tag. Unless it's changed recently I don't think MySQL likes prepared statements. ORACLE on the other hand LOVES them.